# After Calculation the gradients of my paramter w and u, what is the next step to optimize them in a SGD way?

Tags: optimization, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent, cost-based-optimizer

**What I m coding:** I m build an easy neural network with a weight matrix w and a second paramter u for the score. After multipling my input vector with w, the result is multiplied with a vector u to get a result as one figure and that is my score.

**Where I m right now:** I calculated the gradients of both two paramter with respect to my loss function.

**My problem:** And now i m stuck what to do next?

**My solution proposal:** Can I update the paramter with  w = w + learingrate * w_grad (and also for u with u = u learning rate *u_grad) and do this procedure until my cost / loss value decrease... 
does this work? 
Is this correct?
Is this an esay implementation of Stochastic Gradient Descent?

I m coding in Java, if you have an easy and good documented example how to optimize a neural net in an easy way, you can share it with me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: stochastic gradient descent or something else?

Comment: stochastic gradient descent

Comment: Do you want to have single neuron or neural network? If neural network, how many layers?

Comment: Neural network, as described above. Input Layer, Hidden Layer, Output Layer. Input * W --> fsigmoid --> *U --> Output /score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that w_grad is partial derivatives. If to speak of what your solution proposal it is something that is called iterative way of optimization. Just one clarification. Instead of w = w + learingrate * w_grad you should use w = w - learingrate * w_grad. It works fine, but if you have multicore machine, it will use only one core. If you need performance boost you can try batch algorithm. w = w - learingrate * Summ(w_grad). Performance boost is achieved during w_grad calculation